# Access db manager from PlayFramework

Tags: playframework

I was to a conference with Guillaume Bort yesterday evening in Nantes (France) and Play! is really awesome !!

I use it from about 2 weeks.

Guillaume used the URL http://localhost:9000/@db to access his Database and to manage it.

I want to have the same manager but I can't find it !!! :'(

The URL http://localhost:9000/@db is not a valid one with Play-1.1.1, maybe it's for Play-1.2 ?? Because Guillaume was on Play-1.2-alpha yesterday, I don't know.

Does anybody know something about that ??

Thanks !

Florian Bezagu

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The @db URL is part of the new in memory database that ships with version 1.2 of Play, which is H2 (replaces HSQL).

The 1.2 alpha is now available as a download from the playframework download page.

Comment: Thank you, Codemwnci !!

I think I'll wait the official release but I'm impatient of this feature !

Comment: congrats codemwnci, with my upvote you reached 10k reputation! (you certainly deserve it)

Comment: Thanks opensas. I was on vacation as well, so I only just found out myself! My next goal is to get silver, and then gold Playframework badges!

Comment: It doesn't work in _production mode_ it seems... probably for security reasons.

Answer (score 2):

`/@db` also works for the Play's file-stored H2 db (if you set `db=fs` in application.conf). Then, instead of `jdbc:h2:mem:play` (which you use for in-memory db) you should use `jdbc:h2:file:db/h2/play` as JDBC URL.